# vue: A method that is triggered on selection of a year

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to write a method where it checks age property and is triggered on selection of a year

Script:

```
  <script>
  import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
  import {fieldValidComputer} from '../utils/util'
  import ValidatedInput from './subComponents/ValidatedInput'

  export default {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        firstName: '',
        lastName:  '',
        day:       '',
        month:     '',
        year:      '',
        isUnderThree: false
      }
    },
    props: {
      childId:   {required: true},
      canRemove: {required: true},
      inline:    {default: false}
    },
    created: function() {
      this.firstName = this.child.firstName
      this.lastName  = this.child.lastName
      this.day       = this.child.day
      this.month     = this.child.month
      this.year      = this.child.year
    },
    components: {
      'validated-input': ValidatedInput
    },
    methods: Object.assign(
      mapActions(['updateChild', 'removeChild', 'updateQuantity']),
      {
        formUpdate: function() {
          this.updateChild({
            id:            this.childId,
            firstName:     this.firstName,
            lastName:      this.lastName,
            day:           this.day,
            month:         this.month,
            year:          this.year
          })
        },
        delete: function() {
          this.removeChild({ id: this.childId })
        }
      }
    ),
    computed: Object.assign(
      mapGetters(['countryCode', 'getChild', 'numChildren']),
      {
        child: function() {
          return this.getChild(this.childId);
        },
        age: function() {
          var ageDifMs = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime();
          var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
          return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
        }

      },
    )
  }
  </script>
```

I already made an age function where it checks children's ages but what I want now is to prevent someone signing up completely if they enter an age < 3 for their kid. Ideally I think I need a method checkUnderThree that uses the age property and is triggered on selection of a year. This should set a local data property isUnderThree to true(?). If isUnderThree is true, then show the div warning message and make other changes to my vue file. I have the logic but not sure how to execute this. I also wonder whether having it as a computed value instead of a method called on selection of a year will take a lot of processing power for the continued update.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey, you got a lot of unneeded and too complicated looking code

Comment: I'm only putting snippets of code. Other methods are for other stuff ie: other select tags.

Comment: Yes but for example your HTML is too bloated for its purpose

Comment: I'm only asking for help on how to trigger a new method on year selection for checking age < 3. What I put is a snippet of codes of a big project. I don't know how to simplify to make it 'less bloated'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. If you have suggestions then go ahead I'll take it. But up to this point I haven't had any. All those code are mostly done by other people. My task today is to do a method in all those other codes so now when I'm stuck I asked for help.

Comment: I somewhat agree @Badgy' s point. There is multiple things you can do to improve your code. The major thing i see is that you can use [v-for-](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) instead of manually listing the 31 + 12 options. I would suggest also to choose between [shorthand and longhand modifiers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for `isUnderThree`, based on the user inputs (`year`, `month`, and `day`):

```
computed: {
  age() {
    const ageDifMs = Date.now() - this.birthday.getTime();
    const ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
  },
  birthday() {
    const birthday = new Date();
    birthday.setUTCFullYear(this.year);
    birthday.setUTCMonth(this.month);
    birthday.setUTCDate(this.day);
    return birthday;
  },
  isUnderThree() {
    return this.age < 3;
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lmo3z8x8k)

> I also wonder whether having it as a computed value instead of a method called on selection of a year will take a lot of processing power for the continued update.

Computed properties are cached, and they're only re-evaluated when the dependencies change. On the other hand, methods in the template would be re-evaluated whenever the component is rendered. [[1]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)